# Prevent repetitive array setup array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hi I am trying to prevent the repetitive array set. So please help me to simplify this.

```
otherIcons = [
        this.get('fruit_apple').icon,
        this.get('fruit_banana').icon,
        this.get('fruit_cherry').icon,
        this.get('fruit_melon').icon
      ];
```

Since I am changing little bit on every line. Help me to simplify this in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of the substrings that change, then iterate over them:

```
const otherIcons = [
  'activity',
  'adaptive',
  'external_assessment',
  // ...
]
  .map(iconName => this.get(`university.settings.node_icon_${iconName}`).icon);
```